# Quadratic equation - finding $x$ given $y$ value

Tags: quadratics

I've been having trouble with this quadratic equation where $6639.55 = -0.06493x^2 + 22.35175x + 5065.25$. My question is, how do I find out $x$?

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: You will need the quadratic formula!

Comment: The Quadratic Formula is your friend!

Comment: and what is your problem now?

Comment: Not 'AND' but or and $\approx$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the solution of $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ is given by $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ After simplifications you have to solve
$$-0.06493x^2+22.35175x-1613.3=0$$
$$a=-0.06493$$
$$b=22.35175$$
$$c=-1613.3$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the formula! However when I tried to enter all the variables, I ended up with  negative value for some reason... It's 172,1186441 +- -328,0766685, any idea how so?

Comment: Should i write down further steps?